# I don't load the references of the variables with bindParam and PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem and I don't know what it may be, in principle I think I'm doing well but it doesn't insert the data in the database correctly. Instead of inserting the data, what it does is to name the references. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {

$fecha='2018-03-06';
$idoriginal=45646546;
$tcin='09:38:00';
$loca='\\\\prueba\fsdfsdf';

    $con = "INSERT INTO registros_tempo (id, fecha, id_original, tc_in, ta_vt)"
            . " VALUES (NULL, ':fecha', ':id_original', ':tc_in', ':loca');";


    // Prepare the sql statement.
    $consulta=Conexion::conectar()->prepare($con);



    // Bind the input parameters to the prepared statement.

//$consulta->prepare($con);  

$consulta->bindParam(":fecha", $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->bindParam(":id_original", $idoriginal, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consulta->bindParam(":tc_in", $tcin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->bindParam(":loca", $loca, PDO::PARAM_STR);


 //$consulta = $consulta->prepare($con);


    $executar = $consulta->execute();
$consulta->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $ultimoIdInsertado = Conexion::conectar()->lastInsertId();

    // Display last insert id.
    echo 'Registro añadido con id ' . $ultimoIdInsertado;

    // Close connection.
    $consulta = NULL;
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

When I insert in the db instead of appearing...:

01 2018-03-06 45646546 \\prueba\fsdfsdf

I'm getting this other one...:

01 0000-00-00 0 :loca

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

///////////////////////////////////////////////
SOLUTION
Indeed, I was doing something wrong, now if the references happen to me correctly... I don't have to add quotation marks in the references in the consultation of the prepared sentence.

/////////////////////////////////

Comment: what is the fecha column type in your db ?

Comment: For the future reference: [PDO prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared)

Comment: My colum is date in the db